# Как мне глобализировать переменную

Tags: golang

Нужно передать переменную `sss` в качестве аргумента для `go func()`. 
Но я не могу передать переменную в качестве аргумента так как переменная лежит выше, компилятор пишет что переменную `sss` не найдено.

```
func main() {
    host := os.Args[1]
    bat := []string {
        "hello", 
        "goodbye",
        "chain",
    }
    for _, ranges := range bat { //чисто для примера цикл for
        sss := fmt.Sprintf("%s", ranges) //которую нужно использовать в функции ниже
    }

    const (
        rps = true;
    )

    if rps == true {
        go func(host string, header string) {
            req, err := http.Get(host)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            } else {
                fmt.Println(req.Body, req.Header)
            }

        } ("http://google.com", sss) // переменная которая лежит в цикле for
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

переменная лежит в for и после того как он отрабатывает онa уничтожается GC. Вам надо объявить ее выше. и еще убрать : в for. (sss обявите перед for и все полетит)

```
var sss string
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все полетело!